# Raspberry Pi 3 Display Cable, what is it called? How to attach?

Tags: hardware, display, tutorial

I have a Kuman 3.5 inch 320*480 Resolution Touch Screen TFT LCD Display that I wish to interface with using the Raspberry Pi connector S2, display serial interface (DSI), using a 15-pin ribbon cable.  What is the best way to do it?  What is the cable named? (DSI cable)? How can I attach the cable to the RPi 3 board?  Are there special connectors for other devices?

I could not find a clear tutorial.  Would appreciate any links you may forward. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share a link to the display online?

Comment: @MohammadAli - Here is a link to the display https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01CNJVG8K/ref=s9_simh_gw_g147_i2_r?ie=UTF8&fpl=fresh&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=303SV25QWM0XZZP4CGSW&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=6aad23bd-3035-4a40-b691-0eefb1a18396&pf_rd_i=desktop

Comment: Found this: The Raspberry Pi connector S2 is a display serial interface (DSI) for connecting a liquid crystal display (LCD) panel using a 15-pin ribbon cable.

Comment: @MohammadAli - Here is another link http://www.petervis.com/Raspberry_PI/Raspberry_Pi_LCD/Raspberry_Pi_LCD_DSI_Display_Connector.html

Comment: Why do you think it's possible to connect your spi gpio based lcd to the dsi port on your Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This board appears to use the SPI interface and some additional pins from the old 26-pin RasPi connector (their claimed compatibility with the various plus models tell me that the minor changes to the header since 1.0 don't affect them much).

This particular panel is designed to attach directly to the Pi with no intervening cable at all.  SPI is not a hugely tricky protocol, so you *might* be able to get away with an extension cable if you need some distance between display and board, like [this one from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1337).  But otherwise you should be able to line up pin one with pin one and plug it right in so the Pi and the LCD are front-to-back.

Getting the software to drive it configured correctly might be the trickier part, but it looks like the guys [have their own preinjected Raspbian image for that.](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx18A163Y7BI0YM/?). $20 is decently cheap for what you get; I'm tempted to get one myself and try it out.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much.  I shall give it a try.  I am sorry but do not have privileges to up vote your answer. :)